# Using purl to source a .Rmd file from within a Rnw file

Tags: r, r-markdown, knitr

I have done some analysis in a .Rmd file. I now want to use some objects that are created in this file in a report that I'm writing up as a .Rnw file. Since switching from Sweave to knittr as the weaving engine the following happens:

If i run the line `purl(input = 'myfile.Rmd', output = 'myfile.R')` in the console, I get an .R file that only contains the R chunks from the .Rmd file. That is what I want.
If I put this line into the .Rnw file and knit it (the .Rnw file, that is) however, I do end up with a `myfile.R` and no errors, but it is completely empty (except for one linebreak for some reason).

I have also tried to put `knitr::opts_chunk$set(purl = TRUE)` and `knit_hooks$set(purl = hook_purl)` in the .Rmd file and then use `knit()` instead of `purl()` in my .Rnw file, but the result is the same.

The following is a small example:

test.Rnw

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

<<test>>=
  library(knitr)
  purl(input = 'test.Rmd', output = 'test.R')
@

\end{document}
```

test.Rmd

````
```{r}
answer <- 42
```
````

Expected Output:

```
## ------------------------------------------------------------------------
answer <- 42
```

Actual output:

Does anyone have experience with this?
Is this a bug or am I missing something?
Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to `?purl`:

> > **knitr** will try to decide the pattern list based on the filename extension of the input document, e.g. `Rnw` files use the list `apat$rnw`, `tex` uses the list `apat$tex`, `brew` uses `apat$brew` and HTML files use `apat$html`

But apparently, this is not the whole story. Note that [`purl` essentially is just a wrapper to `knit`](https://github.com/yihui/knitr/blob/11ddfc6edbdffa1ad4e161f1cfacc75dd6aaa89d/R/output.R#L276). My conjecture is, while the RNW document is being knitted, there are some global options set that make `knit` just look for RNW-like patterns, even if you're `purl`ing an RMD file from within the RNW document.

To fix this, explicitly set up Markdown patterns by calling `pat_md()` before `purl()`. Afterwards, restore the previous patterns in order to not interfere with the remaining parts of the RNW document.

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

<<test>>=
  library(knitr)
  opat <- knit_patterns$get()
  pat_md()
  purl(input = 'test.Rmd', output = 'test.R')
  knit_patterns$set(opat)
@

\end{document}
```

Comment: I think this might qualify as a [bug](https://github.com/yihui/knitr/issues).

Comment: This worked like a charm, thank you!
I will add it as an issue and mark it as a potential bug.

Answer (score 3):

@Cl.'s conjecture was correct. The function `knitr::knit()` introduces a lot of side-effects, including setting the parsing patterns. In this case, I'd strongly recommend that you run `purl()` in a separate R session. One way to do it is to change

```r
purl(input = 'test.Rmd', output = 'test.R')
```

to

```r
xfun::Rscript_call(purl, list(input = 'test.Rmd', output = 'test.R'))
```

This makes sure `purl()` is called in a new R session that is (pretty much) independent of the current R session, so the parsing patterns set in the current R session will not affect the new R session's `knitr::knit()` call.