# Source RMarkdown chunks

Tags: r, r-markdown

Please consider the following.

For me, the beauty of writing nearly all analyses in a RMarkdown file instead of in R scripts it that RMarkdown offers the possibility to write a report of the analysis while performing/coding it.

Sometimes, specific code snippets are re-used for different outputs. For example: a table created in a RMarkdown code chunk could be used in a Shiny app as well. Currently, I copy/paste the respective code from the RMarkdown into the Shiny app code.

However, when this table would be created in a R script, we can use `source("table_script.R")`. In this way no copy/paste is needed and both the RMarkdown and the Shiny app can make efficient use of this table. However, this (writing separate source-able R scripts) is exactly what I try to avoid when writing an RMarkdown, because otherwise the code chunks in the RMarkdown would have little other use than sourcing a couple of R scripts.

---

### Question

**Is there any way to `source()` (named) RMarkdown chunks?**

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I've thought about this before but couldn't work out how to do it. I ultimately ended up using `knitr::purl()` to capture the 'functions of interest' from the .Rmd into a new .R file, then I used `source()` to get the functions I wanted to reuse (similar to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58694897/using-purl-to-source-a-rmd-file-from-within-a-rnw-file). Would this work for your use-case?

Comment: Thanks. This could be an option, but seems more work than writing the R script directly and source it in the RMarkdown and the Shiny app (in my case).